# Arduino + Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino

I am using Unity and arduino. getcom data from arduino that I receive (string format), after that, I split it and convert it to float. Everything works well, get_x, get_y, get_z are obtained, problem with Single.Tryparse after which angle_x is 0. What could be the problem?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class RightArm : MonoBehaviour {
    string getcom;
    string get_x,get_y,get_z,get_number;
    float angle_x,angle_y,angle_z;
    float number;
    Quaternion originRotation;
    Quaternion next;
    void Start () {
        originRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update () {
        getcom = GameObject.Find ("ScriptHolder").GetComponent<Receiver> ().getcom;
        getcom= getcom.Remove(getcom.Length-1);
        get_number = getcom.Substring (0,getcom.IndexOf(' '));
        getcom = getcom.Remove(0,getcom.IndexOf(' ')+1);
        get_x = getcom.Substring(0, getcom.IndexOf(' '));
        getcom = getcom.Remove(0,getcom.IndexOf(' ')+1);
        get_y = getcom.Substring(0, getcom.IndexOf(' '));
        getcom = getcom.Remove(0,getcom.IndexOf(' '));
        get_z = getcom;     
        Single.TryParse (get_number, out number);
        if (number == 3) {
            Single.TryParse (get_x, out angle_x);
            Single.TryParse (get_y, out angle_y);
            Single.TryParse (get_z, out angle_z);
            Quaternion rotation_x = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle_z, Vector3.right);
            Quaternion rotation_y = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle_x, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion rotation_z = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle_y, new Vector3 (0,0,1));
            transform.rotation = originRotation * rotation_x; 
            next = originRotation * rotation_x;
            transform.rotation = next * rotation_y;
            next = next * rotation_y;
            transform.rotation = next * rotation_z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getcom 3 - 12.66 9.22 -8.33

Comment: for example getcom.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved using:

```
Single.TryParse(get_x, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out angle_x);
```